# How can you create a unit test for a method that detaches a GTK window?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, gtk2

I am creating an application using GTK(v2) in C# on Visual Studio for Mac.

I have created a method that detaches and attaches a window and I would like to create a few unit tests for it. Is there any chance to test this graphical thing?

Here is the class I've created for attaching and detacching:

```
using Gtk;

namespace MyApp.UI.Helpers.Gtk2
{
    public class DetachHelper
    {
        ExternalWindow externalWindow;

        public void Detach (Bin container, Event evt, string windowTitle, Box box, Function func)
        {
            if (externalWindow == null) {
                Log.Debug ("Detaching widget");
                externalWindow = new ExternalWindow ();
                externalWindow.Title = windowTitle;
                int window_width = container.Allocation.Width;
                int window_height = container.Allocation.Height;
                externalWindow.SetDefaultSize (window_width, window_height);
                externalWindow.DeleteEvent += (o, args) => Detach (container, evt, windowTitle, box, func);
                externalWindow.Show ();
                container.Reparent (externalWindow.Box);
                externalWindow.Resize (window_width + 10, window_height);
            } else {
                Log.Debug ("Attaching widget again");
                container.Reparent (box);
                externalWindow.Destroy ();
                externalWindow = null;
            }

            func.Invoke ();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you like to test?

Comment: I have edited the code :) I would like to test the state of the externalWindow when I call the Detach method. Depending on the previous state I would like to check if the window is being detached or re-attached.